# "Watch out for exciting ways..." - is that correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semantics

So, I'm not a native English speaker and the company I work for received some copy for a website. One sentence states: "Watch out for exciting ways to..." etc. Is that correct? Doesn't watch out imply danger or care?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary or Googled the phrase?

Comment: [ODO on watch \[out\] for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/watch?q=watch+out#watch__13): Look out or be on the alert for.

Comment: Eh, a dictionary is not likely to tell me whether or not the sentence conveys the message it needs to. I know it's grammatically correct, I know the definition of watch out. But as Phil stated in his answer, "watch out" is now used to imply excitement. Perhaps I should have phrased my question differently. I was wondering whether or not "watch out" has a negative vibe about it (to me it does).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Watch out" is now a common marketing phrase meant to imply excitement. I still remember a video advertising a product in a shop when I was a child with the phrase "Watch out, there's a wiggly about!".

There is always an exclamation mark. It is never warranted.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to trigger a negative vibe with me, but I guess if it's common nowadays..